# xCode 9 (macOS): Failed to render instance of <NSView subclass>: The Agent crashes

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I’ve just updated to xCode 9 and converted my project to Swift 4. After that, all my `@IBDesignable(s)` subclasses of `NSView` are causing the error in IB. All the other Controls, that are subclasses of `NSButton`, for example, are working just fine. Is someone facing the same problem? Is it an xCode bug (feature)?